# Computing Minkowski Difference For Circles and Convex Polygons

Tags: time-complexity, computational-geometry

I'm needing to implement a Minkowski sum function that can return the Minkowski sum of either 2 circles, 2 convex polygons or a circle and a convex polygon. I found [this](http://www.cs.rug.nl/~bekker/publications/bekker001.PS) thread that explained how to do this for convex polygons, but I'm not sure how to do this for a circle and polygon. Also, how would I even represent the answer?! I'd like the algorithm to run in O(n) time but beggars can't be choosers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Circle is trivial -- just add the center points, and add the radii. Circle + ConvexPoly is nearly as simple: move each segment perpendicularly outward by the circle radius, and connect adjacent segments with circular arcs centered at the original poly vertices. Translate the whole by the circle center point.

As for how you represent the answer: Well, it depends on what you want to do with it. You could convert it to a NURBS if you just want to draw it with a vector drawing library. You could approximate the circular arcs with polylines if you just want a polygonal approximation. Or you might store it as is -- "this polygon, expanded by such-and-such a radius". That would be the best choice for things like raycasting, for instance. Or as a compromise, you could connect adjacent segments linearly instead of with circular arcs, and store it as the union of the (new) convex polygon and a list of circles at the vertices.

Oh, about ConvexPoly + ConvexPoly. That's the trickiest one, but still straightforward. The basic idea is that you take the list of segment vectors for each polygon (starting from some particular extremal point, like the point on each poly with the lowest X coordinate), then merge the two lists together, keeping it sorted by angle. Sum the two points you started with, then apply each vector from the merged vector list to produce the other points.